# Regex match "_" char only if it isn't in a username

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regex-lookarounds, python-re

**Context and Explaination**

I am doing a telegram bot, and i want to add the excape char `"\"` before every `"_"` char that is not in a username (a word starting with `"@"`) like `"@username_"`, to prevent some markdown errors (in fact in telegram the `"_"` char is used to make a string italic).

So, for example, having this string:

```
"hello i like this char _ write me lol_ @myusername_"
```

i want to be matched only the first two `"_"` chars but not the third

---

**Question**

what's the correct way to do this with a regex pattern?

---

**Expected Conditions and Matching**

| Condition | Match |
| --- | --- |
| `"_"` alone: (`"_"`) | **YES** |
| `"_"` in a word without `"@"`: (`"lol_"`) | **YES** |
| `"_"` in a word starting with `"@"`: (`"@username_"`) | **NO** |
| `"_"` in a word containing `"@"` after the `"@"`: (`"lol@username_"`) | **NO** |
| `"_"` in a word containing `"@"` before the `"@"`: (`"lol_@username"`) | **YES** |
| `"_"` in a world like: (`"lol_@username_"`) | first: **YES** second: **NO** |

---

**What i have tried**

so far i arrived at this, but it does not work properly:

```
"(?=[^@]+)(?:\s[^\s]*(_)[^\s]*\s)"
```

**EDIT**

I also want that in this string: `"lol_@username_"` the first char `"_"` to be matched

Comment: [`(?:^|\s)((?:[^@\s]*?)_(?:[^@\s]*?))(?:\s|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/EfPBPx/1)

Comment: @OlvinRoght thank you, but [here](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%3F%3A%5E%7C%5Cs)((%3F%3A%5B%5E%40%5Cs%5D*%3F)_(%3F%3A%5B%5E%40%5Cs%5D*%3F))(%3F%3A%5Cs%7C%24)&test_string=_hi%20hello%20i%20like%20this%20char%20_%20write%20me%20lol_%20myusername_%20something_&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) it doesn't work when removing `"@"`

Comment: Put whole expression into a *positive lookahead*: [`(?= ... )`](https://regex101.com/r/EfPBPx/2)

Comment: @OlvinRoght Just the last bit would suffice: `(?:^|\s)((?:[^@\s]*?)_(?:[^@\s]*?))(?=\s|$)` ([like this](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%3F%3A%5E%7C%5Cs)((%3F%3A%5B%5E%40%5Cs%5D*%3F)_(%3F%3A%5B%5E%40%5Cs%5D*%3F))(%3F%3D%5Cs%7C%24)&test_string=_hi%20hello%20i%20like%20this%20char%20_%20write%20me%20lol_%20myusername_%20something_%20%40myusername_%20&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0))

Comment: Are you extracting or replacing? So you have `"hello i like this char _ write me lol_ @myusername_"`, what is the expected output?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the expected output is regex match only `"_"` char in `" _ "` and `" lol_ "`

Comment: @LeonardoScotti Then Ryszard's answer gives you all you need.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no, check the edit to the question, it works ratly until the last condition of the table happen

Comment: @Philip your is great but it also fails in the last table condition

Comment: @LeonardoScotti The question has changed, it only had the first 3 conditions then. ;)

Comment: @LeonardoScotti [This works](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%3F%3A%5E%7C%5Cs)((%3F%3A%5B%5E%40%5Cs%5D*%3F)_(%3F%3A%5B%5E%40%5Cs%5D*%3F))(%3F%3D%40%7C%5Cs%7C%24)&test_string=_hi%20hello%20i%20like%20this%20char%20_%20write%20me%20lol_%20myusername_%20something_%20%40myusername_%20something_%40username_&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @OlvinRoght's comment, with a small edit, this should do the trick:

**Regex**

`((?:^|\s)(?:[^@\s]*?))(_)((?:[^@\s]*?))(?=@|\s|$)`

**Code example**

```py
import re

text = '_hi hello i like this char _ write me lol_ _word something_ @myusername_ something_@username_'

regex = r"((?:^|\s)(?:[^@\s]*?))(_)((?:[^@\s]*?))(?=@|\s|$)"

# Leave the first and last capturing group as-is and replace the underscore with '\_'
subst = "\\1\\\\_\\3"

print( re.sub(regex, subst, text) )
```

***Expected output:***

```
\_hi hello i like this char \_ write me lol\_ \_word something\_ @myusername_ something\_@username_
```

**Demo**

[See it live](https://regex101.com/r/Iuc6iV/1)

**Note:**

Although this works, @TheFourthBird's answer is faster. (And more elegant I think.)

Answer (score 2):

You could match all non whitspace chars after matching `@` and capture the `_` in a group using an alternation. If the callback of re.sub, check if group 1 exists.

If it does, return an escaped underscore or the excaped group 1 value (which is also an underscore), else return the match to leave it unchanged.

```
@\S+|(_)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qIadiU/1)

```
import re

strings = [
    "_",
    "lol_",
    "@username_",
    "lol@username_",
    "lol_@username",
    "lol_@username_"
]

for s in strings:
    result = re.sub(
        r"@\S+|(_)",
        lambda x: x.group(1).replace("_", r"\_") if x.group(1) else x.group(),
        s
    )
    print(result)
```

Output

```
\_
lol\_
@username_
lol@username_
lol\_@username
lol\_@username_
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you only care about `@` being at the *start* of a word. You can use `re.sub` along with `replace` and `(?:\s|^)[^@]\S+\b` to match the words that fit your spec:

```
import re

s = "hello i like this char _ write me lol_ @myusername_ asd@_a @_asdf"
s = re.sub(r"(?:\s|^)[^@]\S*\b", lambda x: x.group().replace("_", r"\_"), s)
print(s) # => hello i like this char \_ write me lol\_ @myusername_ asd@\_a @_asdf
```

If you care about `@` appearing *anywhere* in a word, try `(?:\s|^)[^@\s]+\b`:

```
s = "he_llo i like this char _ write me lol_ @myusername_ asd@_a @_asdf"
s = re.sub(r"(?:\s|^)[^@\s]+\b", lambda x: x.group().replace("_", r"\_"), s)
print(s) # => he\_llo i like this char \_ write me lol\_ @myusername_ asd@_a @_asdf
```

Per OP comment, sounds like the latest spec is to escape `_` that are anywhere except after `@` in a word:

```
>>> s = "he_llo i lol_@username_ _ write me lol_ @myusername_ asd@_a @_asdf"
>>> re.sub(r"(?:\s|^)[^@]+@", lambda x: x.group().replace("_", r"\_"), s)
'he\\_llo i lol\\_@username_ \\_ write me lol\\_ @myusername_ asd@_a @_asdf'
```

Comment: it works good but i want that for example in `"lol_@username_"` the first `"_"` to be matched and the seond one not

Comment: Updated although you have some other answers by now. That doesn't seem to match your title well, though "(word starting with @)". It's a good idea to add all of your requirements up front to avoid guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

*Extract* with PyPi regex library:

```py
import regex
string = "hello i like this char _ write me lol_ @myusername_"
print(regex.findall(r'(?<!\S)@\w+(*SKIP)(*F)|_', string))
# ['_', '_']
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##Jc2xCsIwEIDhvU9xdmlSxcVVsZMgLkLXQih6NkcvSblEasF3j6IP8H//tCQb/C5nclOQBIIDvoqYhPwABygtMgcgYBoRkqUIN9sLGJiFEoJD4MAGGrc8I4rvHZqymL51Uj9q@yB/75mVVOq4X3Wtbrp5rer2cr5qVZ/021Qb@P@0LnL@AA).

**Explanation**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S                       non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  @                        '@'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount  possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (*SKIP)(*F)              skip the match, search from the failure location
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |                        or
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  _                        a '_' char
```

*Remove* with `re`:

```py
import re
string = "hello i like this char _ write me lol_ @myusername_"
print(re.sub(r'(?<!\S)(@\w+)|_', r'\1', string))
# hello i like this char  write me lol @myusername_
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##Jc1LCsIwFEbheVbx20kSFEGcKnYPnQZClYsJ5sVNSim491hwdEYfp2zN5XTt3ceSuYFJ1MY@vXHH4CiEDI/gP4TmfMXLzQyLlX0jRELIwWKM21KJ0xzJDqLsuimmc12eiqV63A5m0mo061F/rTyBpbns@W@0Fr3/AA).

*Replace* with `re`:

```py
import re
string = "hello i like this char _ write me lol_ @myusername_"
print(re.sub(r'(?<!\S)(@\w+)|_', lambda x: x.group(1) or "-", string))
# hello i like this char - write me lol- @myusername_
```

See [another Python proof](https://tio.run/##Jc1BCsIwEAXQfU/xzaYJ1oK4E8XewW0hRB2aYNKESUpb8O5V8ACPl9Zi43jaNhdS5AKmKhd244ArhCXvIxy8exOKdRlPaxgaM7tCCAQfvUYX1ikTjyaQFlX66SKZ2jw9JNfydtn1dyW7ft6rj64beBMeL4PljKUdOE5JHhUiQxxEg3@uVLVtXw).

Comment: if you change the replacement string from `"-"` to `r"\_"` then the third answer will do what OP requested... assuming telegram usernames only contain word characters `\w`

Comment: @LeonardoScotti Why do you test the PyPi regex pattern at pythex? Did you `import regex` (after installing `pip install regex`)? You should test it with the PCRE option enabled, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XRfYm0/1).

Comment: sorry i noticed and removed the comment

Comment: the third works good but i want that for example in `"lol_@username_"` the first `"_"` to be matched and the seond one not

Comment: @LeonardoScotti Changing the question now is not a good idea in general, it invalidates the current answers. You may remove `(?<!\S)`, and use `@\w+(*SKIP)(*F)|_`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XRfYm0/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i don't have changed the question, i have only clarified it

Comment: @LeonardoScotti No, you added a *condition* and now it requires a different solution, so it is a new question.

Comment: i'm sorry if i done a wrong thing, i appreciate a lot your help, but i did this edit because if you have "lol_@username_" it's only one word but one part of it is an username, i'm sorry because i have to say it before